# How to have radio buttons using vb script?

Tags: vbscript, automation

I was looking to set time on my computer. For that I'm scripting 3 radio buttons of three different countries so that user can set the time zone by selecting one of the radio buttons.

Also please help in below error:

```
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("tzutil.exe /s """ & TimeZoneFriendlyName & "") 
WScript.Echo "Setting the time zone sucessfully."
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eANEP.png)

Comment: VB.NET IsNot vba AndAlso IsNot vbscript

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We would like to help you, but 1) It sounds like you have two questions (_Also_) What is your first question? 2) If you indeed have two questions, please post them separately. 3) Don't post errors as images; post the text of the error. You can edit your question (by clicking on the 'edit' link under the question) and hopefully get a better answer.

Comment: `objShell` needs to contain a `WshShell` object, using `Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

Answer (score 2):

```
<p><b>Search <u>w</u>here</b></p>
<p><INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO CHECKED AccessKey=w> Google <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Wikipedia <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Nethack <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> MSDN <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Australia <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Maps </p>
```

And

```
Sub Search
'   On Error Resume Next
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If tb2(5).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    If tb2(4).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+") & "&cr=countryAU"
    If tb2(3).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:msdn.com+" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    If tb2(2).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=nethack+" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    If tb2(1).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" & tb1.value
    If tb2(0).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\StackOverflow\VBS\Searchterm", tb1.value & vbtab & WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\StackOverflow\VBS\Searchterm")
    If tb3.checked=true then window.close
End Sub
```

You also have got your quotes wrong. `Cmd /k` will allow you to see what happens in CMD, remove it once it works.

```
 WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /k tzutil.exe /s """ & TimeZoneFriendlyName & """"
```

Here's an HTA showing radio buttons, check boxes, buttons, and shows how to implement keyboard access.

```
<HTML> 
<HEAD><TITLE>Search</TITLE>
  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oMyApp" 
    APPLICATIONNAME="Search" 
    BORDER="normal"
    BORDERSTYLE="sunken"
    CONTEXTMENU="yes"
    CAPTION="yes"
    ICON="C:\windows\system32\shell32,-5"
    SCROLL="no"
    SHOWINTASKBAR="yes"
    SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
    SYSMENU="yes"
    WINDOWSTATE="normal"
  />

<style>
BODY  {font-size :100%;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: black;
  background:URL(images/watermark.gif);background-color: white;
  margin-top:20pt; margin-left:40pt; margin-right:10pt ; text-align:Justify}
P  {margin-left:0pt;margin-right:0pt}
</style>



<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Dim Searchterm

Sub Search
'   On Error Resume Next
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    If tb2(5).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/maps/place/" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    If tb2(4).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+") & "&cr=countryAU"
    If tb2(3).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=site:msdn.com+" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    If tb2(2).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=nethack+" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    If tb2(1).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" & tb1.value
    If tb2(0).Checked=True then WshShell.Run "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & Replace(tb1.value, " ", "+")
    WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\StackOverflow\VBS\Searchterm", tb1.value & vbtab & WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\StackOverflow\VBS\Searchterm")
    If tb3.checked=true then window.close
End Sub

Sub Init
    Count = 0
    window.resizeTo 550, 400
'   On Error Resume Next
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    HistoryArr = Split(WshShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\StackOverflow\VBS\Searchterm"), Chr(9))
    tb1.value = HistoryArr(0)
    For each t in HistoryArr
        Count=Count + 1
        Set Hist = document.createElement("OPTION")
        Hist.Text=t
        Hist.Value=Count
        HistoryList.Add(Hist)
        Count=Count + 1
        If Count > 50 then exit For
    next
    tb1.select
'   tb1.focus
End Sub

Sub Paste
    tb1.value=document.parentwindow.clipboardData.GetData("TEXT")
    tb1.select
End Sub

Sub LBTransfer
    x = CLng(HistoryList.Options.selectedindex)
    tb1.value = HistoryList.Options(x).text
    tb1.select
End Sub

Sub LBTransferK
    x = CLng(HistoryList.Options.selectedindex)
    tb1.value = HistoryList.Options(x).text
    HistoryList.focus
End Sub
</script>
</head>

<body Onload=Init>
<p><b>Enter <u>s</u>earch term</b></p>
<p><INPUT Name=tb1 TYPE=Text size=60 AccessKey=s> <INPUT Type=Button onclick=paste Value=Paste AccessKey=p></p> 
<p><b><u>H</u>istory</b></p>
<p><SELECT NAME="HistoryList" SIZE="4" Onclick=LBTransfer OnKeyPress=LBTransferK AccessKey=h>
</SELECT></p>
<p><b>Search <u>w</u>here</b></p>
<p><INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO CHECKED AccessKey=w> Google <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Wikipedia <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Nethack <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> MSDN <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Australia <INPUT Name=tb2 TYPE=RADIO> Maps </p>
<p><INPUT NAME="Search" TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Search" OnClick=Search> <INPUT Name=tb3 TYPE=CHECKBOX CHECKED AccessKey=c> <u>C</u>lose on search</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a radio button with VBscript. You will need to use an HTA or a different wrapper.

The error seems to be a problem of you not setting the shell object

So to use

```
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("tzutil.exe /s """ & TimeZoneFriendlyName & "") 
WScript.Echo "Setting the time zone sucessfully."
```

You first have to have a

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
```

before that